# Ontology using description logic

Tags: ontology, semantics, logic-programming, first-order-logic, answer-set-programming

I wonder how can we make an ontology using Description logic syntax (A-box, T-box) for a staff of a university? What classes, objects, relations, parents, siblings, constraints and interrelationships among them we can make?

I made the below class diagram but not sure if anything else could be added to it.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want help on your UML class diagram or on how to create a DL ontology based on your UML class diagram? Asking how to model staff at a university is too broad since there is possibly an endless list of solutions.

Comment: Having `Professor` inherit from `Faculty` is probably a bad idea.  Inheritance is known as an 'is-a' relationship. This means your diagram states that a `Professor` is a `Faculty`.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse is it possible to please present a simple example through an answer so I can understand?

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse I want to know how to create a DL ontology, so if you could please explain using a simple example?

Answer (score 2):

UML class diagrams can be translated to TBoxes and object diagrams to ABoxes. See for instance https://henrietteharmse.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/uml-class-diagram-to-owl-and-sroiq-reference.pdf.